Photoshop smartobject saving messes up the format
I purchased a psd file and i encountered an issue while saving a .psb file. I have a video showing the issue: https://streamable.com/q9el2v
I edit the .psb and move things around, save it to the same position, it shows messed up.
I am thinking the file i purchased uses a newer version of photoshop. I tried myself with 2015, 2017 versions.
I can't test newer photoshop versions because i am on windows 8.1
Could the issue be from something else?

Did you change the resolution of either canvas? Does the same thing happen if you open the smart object, do nothing, save, does it still move?

@cybernetic.nomad
here is the psd file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LmRm1DflPs5OgTtt7_iTfvNzQdEEZP_R/view?usp=sharing

@AndrewH
i didnt do anything myself just tried to edit the original smartobject,
it does still move

The thing is on the left side of the bag graphic if i edit that smartobject and when i save it, is showing correctly

I can't reproduce the problem in the latest Photoshop CC 2024. I opened the PSD and moved the object in the smart object, and it seems to work as expected.  Might be because you are using an old version. It's impossible to tell for sure.

@billy
i figured it could be from older versions
